# Failed to start typst-ws(typst-ws) process: Error: spawn typst-ws ENOENT

Tags: typst

When I have installed the typst-LSP and the typst preview extension on my vscode using wsl remote connection, I tried to use the preview function to split my current vscode window the get the pdf. But the vscode reminde my that

```
Failed to start typst-ws(typst-ws) process: Error: spawn typst-ws ENOENT
```

And

```
Failed to find typst-ws executable at /home/hnyls2002/.vscode-
server/extensions/mgt19937.typst-preview-0.5.0-linux-x64/out/typst-ws,maybe we didn't ship 
it for your platform? Using typst-ws from PATH
```

That is the typst-ws ? I don't see it anywhere else.

I also install the typst app using Rust, I can use `typst watch *.typ` command to contiously compile a typst file into PDF. I wonder does the preview function in vscode require the typst app? And how can I fix the above mentioned problem to correctly preview typst in my vscode.

Comment: Strangely enough, I had this issue and it was resolved by restarting my computer. Also, typst-preview has undergone significant updates since July, so it might be worth updating and seeing if the issue persists